# interpreting causality() in R for Granger Test

Tags: r, time-series, granger-causality

As shown in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vars/versions/1.5-2/topics/causality), after running a vector autoregression model (VAR), one can continue with the causality command for Granger tests:

```
causality(x, cause = NULL, vcov.=NULL, boot=FALSE, boot.runs=100)
```

This is the example in the documentation,

```
data(Canada) # below is the data structure

>               e     prod       rw     U
>1980 Q1 929.6105 405.3665 386.1361  7.53
>1980 Q2 929.8040 404.6398 388.1358  7.70
>1980 Q3 930.3184 403.8149 390.5401  7.47
>1980 Q4 931.4277 404.2158 393.9638  7.27
>1981 Q1 932.6620 405.0467 396.7647  7.37

var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const")
causality(var.2c, cause = "e")
```

which returns

```
$Granger

Granger causality H0: e do not Granger-cause prod rw U

data:  VAR object var.2c

F-Test = 6.2768, df1 = 6, df2 = 292, p-value = 3.206e-06
```

My question is: what is this Granger test for and how to interpret it?

It says in the results that the null hypothesis is "H0: **e** do not Granger-cause **prod** **rw** **U**", does that mean it is testing whether **e** Granger causes **prod**, **rw**, **U** all at the same time with one p-value?

When using `grangertest()` in `R`, one always needs to specify both a cause and the dependent variable, so it is not entirely intuitive for me how `causality()` works.

Comment: The R package generalCorr has a function causeSummary(cbind(y,x1,x2)) which will
compute instantaneous causality without assuming linearity and time lags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [W]hat is this Granger test for and how to interpret it?

Basically, Granger causality $x \xrightarrow{Granger} y$ exists when using lags of $x$ next to the lags of $y$ for forecasting $y$ delivers better forecast accuracy than using only the lags of $y$ (without the lags of $x$).

You can find definitions and details in Wikipedia and in free textbooks and lecture notes online. There are also many examples on this site, just check the threads tagged with [granger-causality](/questions/tagged/granger-causality).

> It says in the results that the null hypothesis is "H0: **e** do not Granger-cause **prod** **rw** **U**", does that mean it is testing whether **e** Granger causes **prod**, **rw**, **U** all at the same time with one p-value?

You are right. Note that in a 4-variable VAR(2) model, testing whether one variables does not cause the other three amounts to testing $3 \times 2$ zero restrictions (three variables times two lags), and that is also what the test summary shows: `df1=6`.

> When using `grangertest()` in `R`, one always needs to specify both a cause and the dependent variable, so it is not entirely intuitive for me how `causality()` works.

This is because in a $K$-variate system with $K>2$ there are many possible causal links. $x_i$ may cause $x_j$; $x_i$ may cause $x_j$ and $x_k$; $x_i$ and $x_j$ may cause $x_k$; etc. So the function requires you to specify precisely which causal link you want to examine.

Comment: This is it! I thought I knew enough about Granger causality but actually I have only seen the "x to y" version, not "x to y1, y2, y3." Your answer clarifies a lot!

Comment: @carl_pch, nice to hear that :)